# How to use Manipulate to rotate two vectors in 3D spanned by a arc of a disc?

Tags: plotting

I've provided the code that generates the diagram labelled 'WHAT I HAVE NOW' on the left. I want to modify this code to resemble the diagram on the right, where I've used PAINT.net to illustrate the desired appearance in my Manipulate function.

```
axes2a = Graphics3D[{
    {Red, Opacity[0.8], 
     Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1.8, 0, 0}}, axisDiameter]}, {Red, 
     Opacity[0.8], Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1.8, 0, 0}}, axisDiameter]},
    {Green, Opacity[0.8], 
     Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, -1.8, 0}}, axisDiameter]}, {Green, 
     Opacity[0.8], Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1.8, 0}}, axisDiameter]},
    {Yellow, Opacity[0.8], 
     Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1.8}}, axisDiameter]}, {Yellow, 
     Opacity[0.8], Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1.8}}, axisDiameter]},
    {Blue, Opacity[1], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.1]}}, Boxed -> False, 
   ImageSize -> 500, ViewAngle -> 0.3407215257382556`, 
   ViewPoint -> {1.3285885414244383`, 2.009065646881962`, 
     2.37665893937571`}, 
   ViewVertical -> {0.914917719283248`, 0.2561837807509655`, 
     0.3119221656466261`}];

st = {FontColor -> GrayLevel[.7]};
n2[theta_, phi_] := {Cos[theta], Sin[theta]*Cos[phi], 
   Sin[theta]*Sin[phi]};

scatPlane = 
  ParametricPlot3D[
   RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, n2[phi, theta]}].{r*Sin[Pi/2]*
      Sin[\[Phi]], r*Cos[\[Phi]]*Sin[Pi/2], r*Cos[Pi/2]}, {r, 0, 
    1.5}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, Mesh -> None];

Framed[Manipulate[
  Show[axes2a,  
   ParametricPlot3D[
    RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, n2[phi, 0]}].{r*Sin[Pi/2]*Sin[\[Phi]], 
      r*Cos[\[Phi]]*Sin[Pi/2], r*Cos[Pi/2]}, {r, 0, 1.5}, {\[Phi], 0, 
     2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, Mesh -> None], 
   Graphics3D[{Red, Opacity[0.8], 
     Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, 1.8*n2[phi, 0]}, axisDiameter]}]], {phi, 
   0, 2 Pi}, Paneled -> False], FrameMargins -> 30, 
 Background -> Black, BaseStyle -> st, RoundingRadius -> 10]
```

[image]

I want to add a new slider named 'theta2,' ranging from 0 to 180 degrees. Another angle called theta represents the angle between the two blue vectors, which are currently missing in my existing code. As I adjust theta2, I aim for the yellow partial disc positioned between these two vectors to dynamically change along with the blue vectors.

The blue vector on the left makes an angle theta2 with respect to the z-axis and the one on the right makes an angle of arg[theta2] with respect to the z-axis where

```
E0 = 1;

Telec[theta2_] = E0*(1 - Cos[theta2)/(2 - Cos[theta2]);

arg[theta2_] = ((1 + E0)*Telec[theta2])/(
  E0*Sqrt[Telec[theta2]^2 + 2*Telec[theta2]]);
```

and where theta = theta2 + arg[theta2].

The problem is that I don't know how to do this step and I was hoping someone could offer some advice.

Thank you very much for your time in reading my request.

UPDATE:

The following code includes one blue vector which I am trying to rotate it so it stays on the disk surface as I change the angle theta. The problem is that it only works if phi = 0 or if phi does not equal zero but theta = 0. (See images below)

```
axisDiameter = 0.02;

axes2 = Graphics3D[{
    {Red, Opacity[0.8], 
     Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1.8, 0, 0}}, axisDiameter]}, {Red, 
     Opacity[0.8], Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1.8, 0, 0}}, axisDiameter]},
    {Green, Opacity[0.8], 
     Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, -1.8, 0}}, axisDiameter]}, {Green, 
     Opacity[0.8], Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1.8, 0}}, axisDiameter]},
    {Yellow, Opacity[0.8], 
     Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1.8}}, axisDiameter]}, {Yellow, 
     Opacity[0.8], Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1.8}}, axisDiameter]},
    {Blue, Opacity[1], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.1]}}, Boxed -> False, 
   ImageSize -> 500, ViewAngle -> 0.3407215257382556`, 
   ViewPoint -> {0.5790128723698645`, 1.537083678221584`, 
     2.9583978535306628`}, 
   ViewVertical -> {0.7978154165388095`, 0.2882456528444152`, 
     0.5295328174431713`}];

n2[theta_, phi_] := {Cos[theta], Sin[theta]*Cos[phi], 
   Sin[theta]*Sin[phi]};

vecNorm[phi_] := 
  Graphics3D[{Red, Opacity[0.8], 
    Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, 1.8*n2[phi, 0]}, axisDiameter]}];

vecTes[phi_, theta_] := 
  Graphics3D[{Blue, Opacity[0.8], 
    Rotate[Arrow@
      Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, 1.8*n2[phi + Pi/2, theta]}, axisDiameter], 
     theta, n2[phi, 0]]}];

plane2[phi_] := 
  ParametricPlot3D[
   RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, n2[phi, 0]}].{r*Sin[Pi/2]*Sin[\[Phi]], 
     r*Cos[\[Phi]]*Sin[Pi/2], r*Cos[Pi/2]}, {r, 0, 1.5}, {\[Phi], 0, 
    2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Mesh -> None];

Framed[Manipulate[
  Show[axes2, plane2[phi], vecNorm[phi], vecTes[phi, theta]], {theta, 
   0, 2 Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, Paneled -> False], FrameMargins -> 30, 
 Background -> Black, BaseStyle -> st, RoundingRadius -> 10]
```

[image]

Can some one help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

UPDATE 2: BLUE VECTORS ON PLANE BUT PLANE NOT BETWEEN VECTORS

Thanks to N.J.Evans, I have managed to now have the two blue vectors always lying on the yellow disc. See image below

[image]

Here is the code that generated the above image.

```
(*This is the axis diameter of the axis tubes*)
arrowDiameter = 0.02;

(*Base style for Frame around Manipulate*)
st = {FontColor -> GrayLevel[.7]};

(*This defines the x-, y-, z- coordinate system (red arrow, green \
arrow, yellow)*)
axes2 = Graphics3D[{
    {Red, Opacity[0.8], 
     Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1.8, 0, 0}}, arrowDiameter]}, {Red, 
     Opacity[0.8], 
     Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1.8, 0, 0}}, arrowDiameter]},
    {Green, Opacity[0.8], 
     Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, -1.8, 0}}, arrowDiameter]}, {Green, 
     Opacity[0.8], 
     Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1.8, 0}}, arrowDiameter]},
    {Yellow, Opacity[0.8], 
     Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1.8}}, arrowDiameter]}, {Yellow, 
     Opacity[0.8], 
     Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1.8}}, arrowDiameter]},
    {Blue, Opacity[1], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.1]}}, Boxed -> False, 
   ImageSize -> 500, ViewAngle -> 0.3407215257382556`, 
   ViewPoint -> {0.5790128723698645`, 1.537083678221584`, 
     2.9583978535306628`}, 
   ViewVertical -> {0.7978154165388095`, 0.2882456528444152`, 
     0.5295328174431713`}];

(*x-prime axis *)
xprime[phi2_, theta2_] := {Cos[phi2], Sin[phi2]*Cos[theta2], 
   Sin[theta2]*Sin[phi2]};

(*define x-prime arrow (Red)*)
xprimeArrow[phi2_] := 
  Graphics3D[{Red, Opacity[0.8], 
    Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, 1.8*xprime[phi2, 0]}, arrowDiameter]}];

(*First Blue arrow that always lies in the plane and makes an angle \
of theta2 w.e.t the z-axis (yellow axis)*)
blueArrow1[phi2_, theta2_] := 
  Graphics3D[{Blue, Opacity[0.8], 
    Rotate[Arrow@
      Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, 1.8*xprime[phi2 + Pi/2, 0]}, arrowDiameter], 
     theta2 + Pi/2, xprime[phi2, 0]]}];

(*Defining the angle arg w.r.t the otherside of the z-axis (yellow \
axis) for the second blue vector*)
E0 = 1;
Telec[theta2_] = E0*(1 - Cos[theta2])/(2 - Cos[theta2]);
arg[theta2_] = ((1 + E0)*Telec[theta2])/(
  E0*Sqrt[Telec[theta2]^2 + 2*Telec[theta2]]);

(*Second Blue arrow that always lies in the plane and makes an angle \
of arg w.r.t the z-axis (yellow axis)*)
blueArrow2[phi2_, theta2_] := 
  Graphics3D[{Blue, Opacity[0.8], 
    Rotate[Arrow@
      Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, 1.8*xprime[phi2 + Pi/2, 0]}, arrowDiameter], 
     arg[theta2] + Pi/2, xprime[phi2, 0]]}];

(*This is the disc I would like to always be between blueArrow1 and \
blueArrow2 the part shaded red in the diagram (not working properly \
atm)*)
disc[phi2_, theta2_] := 
  ParametricPlot3D[
   RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, xprime[phi2, 0]}].{r*Sin[Pi/2]*
      Sin[\[Phi]], r*Cos[\[Phi]]*Sin[Pi/2], r*Cos[Pi/2]}, {r, 0, 
    1.5}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
    Mesh -> None];

(*Ouptput manipulation plot*)
Framed[Manipulate[
  Show[axes2, disc[phi2, theta2], xprimeArrow[phi2], 
   blueArrow1[phi2, theta2], blueArrow2[phi2, theta2]], {theta2, 
   0.001, -2 Pi}, {phi2, 0, 2 Pi}, Paneled -> False], 
 FrameMargins -> 30, Background -> Black, BaseStyle -> st, 
 RoundingRadius -> 10]
```

The last piece of the puzzle is to determine how to position the disc consistently between the two blue arrows, forming the red shaded region, for any angle theta2. I attempted to adjust the `{\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}` parameters in the disc definition (see following code), but the results were nonsensical. I'm hoping someone can guide me on the correct approach.

```
disc[phi2_, theta2_] := 
  ParametricPlot3D[
   RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, xprime[phi2, 0]}].{r*Sin[Pi/2]*
      Sin[\[Phi]], r*Cos[\[Phi]]*Sin[Pi/2], r*Cos[Pi/2]}, {r, 0, 
    1.5}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
    Mesh -> None];
```

The angle theta2 is a number ranging from 0 to pi. The angle arg is given in the code as follows

```
(*Defining the angle arg w.r.t the otherside of the z-axis (yellow \
axis) for the second blue vector*)
E0 = 1;
Telec[theta2_] = E0*(1 - Cos[theta2])/(2 - Cos[theta2]);
arg[theta2_] = ((1 + E0)*Telec[theta2])/(
  E0*Sqrt[Telec[theta2]^2 + 2*Telec[theta2]]);
```

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to account for `theta` twice  Try:`vecTes[phi_, theta_] := Graphics3D[{Blue, Opacity[0.8], Rotate[Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, 1.8*n2[phi + Pi/2, 0]}, axisDiameter], theta, n2[phi, 0]]}];`

Comment: Hey N.J.Evans! Thanks a bunch for spotting that. With your help I managed to also include the second blue vector and they both now always lie on the yellow plane. The last piece of the puzzle is how to make the plane always lie between the two blue arrows. (For those who might be interested in solving this last piece of the puzzle I have included the latest code. Please see below)

Comment: Looks neat. If this is some project, consider posting on [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com) - we might select for Staff Picks: https://wolfr.am/StaffPicks Note on Wolfram Community you can simply upload a notebook and it will automatically become a post.